# How can I connect a sveltekit app to a mysql db?

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection, sveltekit

I am on Centos 7, on a vps with cpanel and phpmyadmin.
The db is created via phpmyadmin and I can’t connect.
I use node adaptor.

+page.svelte

```
<script>
  export let data;
  console.log(data);
</script>
```

+server.js

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';
let mysqlconn = null;
// /** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */

export const load = () => {
    if (!mysqlconn) {
        mysqlconn = mysql.createConnection({ 
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'exem_sveltekit2',
            password: '***************',
            database: 'exem_utilisateurs'
        });
    }
    return {mysqlconn};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a connection from server to client. Everything you return has to be serializable to JSON (to some extent - the transfer format is not strictly JSON).

Even if you could do this, it would be a very bad idea to just let any user create queries against the DB. Get the data needed for the page and only return that.

Also, the load function probably should be in the file [`+page.server.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-server-js). [`+server.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) is for more custom APIs.